# Normalize spaces in string to 1 space

Tags: freemarker

Input string :  input= `"1222   d1212     transferx 111111111 kkk 111111111111111"`

FTL :

```
<#assign op=input?split(" ")?join("','")>${op}
```

Current op : `1222','','','d1212','','','','','transferx','111111111','kkk','111111111111111`

Expected o/p :  `1222,d1212,transferx,111111111,kkk,111111111111111`

How to normalize the spaces in string to 1 space so that above FTL will give expected o/p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get why you do a `?split` and then a `?join`. Why not use [`?replace`](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_replace)?

And, what about this scenario: `"  a  b c "`? That will result in `",a,b,c,"`. So, I think you want to [`?trim`](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_trim) your string first. So:

```
"  a  b c "?trim?replace("\\s+", ",", "r")
```

See also:

- https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<#assign op=input?split("\\s+", "r")?join(",")>
```

The second parameter `r` of the split builtin indicates that the first parameter is a regular expression. The `\\s+` regular expression means one or more space.